# Symfony2 FOSUSerBundle disable automatic logout after a period of inactivity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i can't seem to find the solution on how to disable auto logout after inactivity? Id like the sessions to stay alive until the browser window is closed.

Is it just the the session: config in the config files that is causing the logout or is it some FOSUSerBundle config i cannot seem to find??

Comment: how to you authenticate? with a token? is there a token ttl defined anywhere (e.g. I am using jwt authentication and there is a token_ttl to set for)

Comment: Look if you have session configuration in config.yml, or session_max_idle_time in parameters.yml. Perhaps it specifies somewhere idle time or session lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the sesion life time like this:

```
framework:
    session:
            cookie_lifetime: 60 #60 seconds
            gc_maxlifetime: 50 #50 seconds - only needed for testing. Dont use this in a production environment
            gc_probability: 1 #only needed for testing. Dont use this in a production environment
            gc_divisor: 1 #only needed for testing. Dont use this in a production environment
```

Complete code: https://reformatcode.com